# How to define a "*" or "ANY" in routes in Play2?

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0

In play1, we can define in routes:

```
*  /users    Users.index
```

But the `*` can't be used in play2. If I write:

```
*  /users   controllers.Users.index
```

It will report error:

```
Compilation error
HTTP Verb expected
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not supported. To be fair is not something you would like to do anyway.

In HTTP each method (GET, POST) has its own characteristics and usage (idempotence, for example) and having a controller's method behaving differently as per HTTP method used doesn't seem a good idea :)